# Can I Send notifications to specific users in firebase cloud messaging console

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I was wondering if we can select specific users directly from the console in order to send notifications to.

If we can't how can I achieve that. I have a node server and a react-native app that I want to send notifications to.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send notifications from the console to specific users by following the steps below:

1. Get the FCM registration tokens for the users' devices. *You can check how to get the tokens for the devices depending on the platform [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders).*
2. Go to the project's [Notification Composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification).
3. Enter the notification details *i.e notification title(optional),
   notification text, notification image(optional), notification name(optional)*.
4. Click *Send test message*.
5. Enter the FCM registration tokens.
6. Click *Test*.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it is more practical to make an API to send notifications then to do this

Comment: Yeah. You can use Cloud Functions for that. Check out some sample code here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/fcm-notifications

Comment: but the problem is the database Im using is mongoDB and this require firebase storage

Comment: You can use your custom database/server to do this too. Checkout this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server